# How to correct VB6 application blocking execution of other user session application launch?

Tags: vb6, windows-xp

We have a Visual Basic 6 application suite running on Windows XP that uses a shared DLL component - a login window - that is an ActiveX EXE. This login window is separate from the applications that call it.

If I launch the application that uses the login screen, and leave the login screen up (do not enter user credentials), and then launch another one of the applications as a different user (right-click "Run As..."), the second user instance of the application will not launch until the first user either closes the login screen or enters their credentials.

If I instead launch the login ActiveX EXE first, then launch the application that calls it, I do not have an issue with blocking.

Is this normal behavior? Should there be an issue with two separate users running applications in this manner? I am not understanding why the first user session is blocking the second user session.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveX EXE classes can be compiled to either permit multiple or single instances.

I'm guessing this component is in single-instance mode, and spawns a modal dialog box for the login.

I'm unsure as to whether the "multiple instances" thing covers AxEXE processes under multiple users, but it may just be the check for another instance, coupled with the modal dialog not permitting a thread to run through that class to do the instance check, that causes the blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Without a lot more detail all we can do is guess.

One possibility is that your ActiveX EXE is written so that its clients create an instance of some Class in it then invoke a method on this to bring up a logon Form.  Is it possible that every instance of this Class tries to make use of the same predeclared instance of your logon Form?

When you define a Form you get two things, a "Form Class" you can create instances of and a "free" global predeclared instance of that Class with the same name.

You might try creating a new local instance of the Form within your connector Class and use that.  Then each client gets his own copy.

Comment: The clients create an instance of the ActiveX EXE if it does not already exist. However, is this behavior supposed to work across user profiles? I thought if I ran as another user, the applications would be in their own execution space, so that a call from user B would not be impacted by what is executing for user A.

Comment: Look in the VB6 documentation and code samples for the "Coffee Monitor" tutorial.  The clients can even be on different PCs and use the same running instance of an ActiveX EXE.